# Memory management with bitmaps

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management

I am reading **Tanenbaum's Modern operating systems**. I am not able to understand what he means by last line in the attached image. He says that **the run may straddle word boundaries in the bitmap**. What does he mean by that? Can someone explain it to me?

[image: memory management with bitmaps]

Comment: In a bitmap, bits are packed in one or more words. That adds complexity to the processing as you need to work simultaneously at the word and bit levels.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But here bitmap is created based on allocation units which consist of words.

Comment: To me that means "the run may be split across adjacent words" (which IMO is not that big of a deal, not compared to doing a linear search in the first place)

Comment: @chanzerre: right. That does not impact my comment.

Comment: @chanzerre Suppose you have a bitmap like (8-bit words) 11000000 00000010 00010001 and you want to allocate 8 units. That means 6 units from the first word of the bitmap and 2 units from the second.